# ion list change the color of an item when is pressed

Tags: html, sass, ionic2, ionic3

I have an `ion-list` of `ion-item` that are clickable. I would like to change the color of the selected item in the list when it is clicked, and only in that moment; so, when the user stops pressing the item, its color changes to the default one.
I could only find to change the color when the item is pressed, but the color remains even after I stop pressing the item.

Edit: This is the html code for the list:

```
<ion-list>
<ion-item *ngFor="let tag of tagList; let i=index" (click)="addSelectedTag(i)">
<h2> {{tag.val().name}}</h2>
</ion-item>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: are the itens coming from a `ngFor` or are you hard coding them?

Comment: Could you please add the html code of that list?

Comment: Yep, I've modified the question with the html code.

Comment: where you able to solve this issue?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In order to do so, you'd need to set the following sass variables (in your `variables.scss`) file:

```
$list-ios-activated-background-color: #d9d9d9;
$list-md-activated-background-color: #f1f1f1;
$list-wp-activated-background-color: #aaa;
```

These are the **default** colors, so change them as needed on your end.

And then make sure your items are **buttons** (*they won't look like buttons, is just to use their clickable properties and styles*):

```
<ion-list>
  <button ion-item *ngFor="let tag of tagList; let i=index (click)="addSelectedTag(i)">
    <h2> {{tag.val().name}}</h2>
  </button>
</ion-list>
```

Comment: This works only for button items (`<button ion-item></button>`) inside a list, if op has a normal `<ion-item></ion-item>` inside the list this'll not have effect. +1 for simple solution.

Comment: You're absolutely right... since the OP didn't include the code, I assumed the items were _button items_ (the user mentioned _[...] that are clickable._). I'll ask the user to include the code just in case if that's not the real scenario. Thanks for pointing this out :)

Comment: I have modified the questione with the html code! Thanks